# 2-D Dirac Delta in Polar Coordinate

Tags: polar-coordinates, dirac-delta

In Section 7.3.2 of Fourier Methods in Imaging (by Dr. Roger Easton Jr), it is stated that for 2-D Dirac delta located on the x-axis at a distance $\alpha > 0$,

$x = r$ and $y = r_0 \theta$

Thus the polar representation would be:
$\delta[x-\alpha]\delta[y] = \delta[r-r_0]\delta[r_0 \theta]$

I do not understand why $y = r_0 \theta$ instead of $y=r_0 tan\theta$?

It also states that the radial coordinate is directed along the x-axis and  the azimuthal displacement due to the angle (what angle?) is parallel to the y-axis. What angle are we talking about? Why is there a displacement parallel to the y-axis if the delta is located on x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's on the $x$ axis any $\theta$ must be small. For small $\theta$, $\tan\theta\approx\theta$

Comment: Thank you, but still do not quite grasp this concept. So, I have updated the question with more confusions.

Comment: You want to describe the function in the vicinity of $(r_0,0)$. The function has two coordinates, $x$ and $y$. In general, you can write in polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Now both $r$ and $\theta$ can vary. A small change in $\theta$ has only second order effects around $\theta_0=0$ $(\cos\theta\approx 1-\theta^2/2)$, so all changes in $x$ are due to the change in radius. Similarly, changes in radius have very little effect on $y$ around $y=0$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!